# VBA Index/Match - Avoid Source Dialogue

Tags: excel, vba, macos, indexing, match

I have a workbook setup for users that have a few cells index/matched to a serperate workbook. The issue I am running into is these user books are sometimes opened on Mac, and sometimes PC, causing issues with the Index/Match formula. My first attempted solution was this:

```
ThisWorkbook.UpdateLink Name:=ThisWorkbook.LinkSources
```

However when this was assigned to a macro button, it causes a dialogue box to open for the user to select the source.

I instead have tried to set up two seperate macros; one for Mac and one for PC (Not unusual on this sheet as i've had to duplicate a fair bit for Mac/PC compatibility), and these macros paste the required formula directly to the cell. However, this still causes the choose source dialogue to open.

```
Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Tracker")

ws.Range("J3").Formula = "=INDEX('[Workflow 19-20 LIVE.xlsm]PLAN'!$F:$F,MATCH(I3,'[Workflow 19-20 LIVE.xlsm]PLAN'!$A:$A,0))"
```

Is there any way I can avoid the dialogue box situation? I really don't want to give users any options here.

Comment: Maybe look into the `Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro` method.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to reproduce the problem with the dialogue.

Comment: It asks users for a source when the files specified aren't already open.